# Nexus One crashes with 32GB SD card

Tags: external-sd, nexus-one

I just got a Nexus One (Gingerbread), and when I put in my 32GB Micro SDHC it will crash when it tries to read it (copying apps, opening storage settings, etc) and after you have locked the screen it will not come back on (the menu buttons light up, but not the screen)

I re-formatted it on my computer, but when I used it in my phone it would fail again.

The card however works on my old Huawei Ideos u8150 (Froyo) with no problems.

The Nexus one reads the 8GB card that came with it fine.

I would like to know why the Nexus would do this, given that they are spec'd to read a 32GB card. And how to fix it, obviously.

I have now tried formatting it with another phone (along with formatting it with GParted) and it works until you plug it into the computer and copy files onto it. It will then either not mount it or act the same as above.

Comment: Thank you for letting us know -- but could you also make clear what your question is? a) what cards are compatible b) what size is supported c) what phones are compatible to the card d) how to make your Nexus work with that specific card e) ... ?

Answer (score 1):

32 Gb cards work just perfectly on my Nexus One. I have original ROM which was updated once OTA. The phone reports OS version as 2.3.6. I use SD card preformatted as FAT 32. You can try to format your card using phone itself, go in storage settings and erase the card. It should work after.

Comment: I have actually since sold my Nexus (Partly because of this issue). I did try formatting the card with the phone, but this ended up with the phone crashing/ not responding. The card was formatted to FAT 32 by my computer originally. It was running Gingerbread 2.3.6 if I remember correctly. I've used (and am using) this same card with my Galaxy Tab 2 and my Galaxy S without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be a software bug.

Have you tried formatting it with the phone itself yet?

Else: The Nexus One is now unsupported by Google, so if this is the case you can only fix it by installing some aftermarket firmware like CyanogenMod and see if this solves your problem.

CyanogenMod has a [device page for the N1](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices/nexus-one) and a [full update guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Nexus_One%3a_Full_Update_Guide). If you want to try even more, there are also unsupported beta firmwares for Ice-Cream-Sandwich and Jelly-Bean available on [XDA's Nexus One development forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=559) from other developers.

Comment: I don't recommend Ice Cream Sandwich or Jelly Bean on a working device. 
It's working, but in my opinion kinda slow. I suggest to flash the latest CM7.